# How to show that $\sum {2^j + j \over 3^j - j}$ converges

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I'm not quite sure how to go about growing the numerator or shrinking the denominator to perform a tricky comparison test, or hashing out the ratio test, so any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**:

$$\frac{2^j + j}{3^j - j} \le \frac{2^j + 2^j}{3^j - j} \le \frac{2^j + 2^j}{3^j - \frac{1}{2} 3^j}$$

for all sufficiently large $j$.

Answer (score 1):

$\dfrac{2^j + j}{3^j - j}-\dfrac{2^j}{3^j}
=\dfrac{3^j(2^j + j)-2^j(3^j - j)}{3^j(3^j - j)}
=\dfrac{j(3^j+2^j)}{3^j(3^j - j)}
$,
so
$\big|\dfrac{2^j + j}{3^j - j}-\dfrac{2^j}{3^j}\big|
=\big|\dfrac{j(3^j+2^j)}{3^j(3^j - j)}\big|
<\big|\dfrac{2j3^j)}{3^j(3^j - j)}\big|
=\big|\dfrac{2j}{3^j - j}\big|
$.

All you need now
is 
$\lim_{j \to \infty}
\dfrac{j}{3^j}= \ 0
$.

Answer (score 1):

The terms are positive, and asymptotically equal to $$a_j=\frac{2^{j}}{3^j}$$ That is, if $b_j$ is your sequence, $\lim\limits_{j\to\infty}\dfrac{a_j}{b_j}=1$. Can your prove this?

Comment: Thanks for that comment Pedro. :+)