# Determine if the following series are convergent or divergent?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

How to determine if the following series are convergent or divergent? I'm supposed to use here the limit comparison test, but I don't know how to choose the second series.
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \ln(1+ \sqrt{\frac 2k})$$
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty\displaystyle \sqrt[k]{e}\sin(\frac{\pi}{k}).$$

Comment: For the second one, can't we use a variation of the harmonic series?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [related problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/571119/show-the-following-series-converges/571128#571128). Since

> $$ \lim_{k\to \infty }\frac{\ln(1+\sqrt{2/k})}{\sqrt{2/k}}=1, $$

then the series diverges by the fact:

> Suppose $\sum_{n} a_n$ and $\sum_n b_n $ are series with positive terms, then
>
> if $\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{a_n}{b_n}=c>0$, then either both series converge or diverge.

**Note:** We used the Taylor series

> $$ \ln(1+t)=t+O(t^2)\implies \ln(1+t)\sim t. $$
>
> $$e^t\sin(\pi t)= \pi t+O(t^2)\implies e^t\sin(\pi t) \sim \pi t.$$