# Evaluate limit of integral of sequence of function

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, functions, definite-integrals

Evaluate

> $$\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\sqrt{n}(e^{-x/n}-1)}{x}dx.$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** You can interchange the limit with the integral if the sequence converges uniformly. So, can you prove that the sequence converges uniformly?

Comment: thanks for your prompt response! I get your point. For this sequence of function should i prove $\frac{\sqrt{n}(e^{-x/n}-1)}{x}$ uniformly converges to $\frac{e^{-x}-1}{x}$?

Comment: Try to find the pointwise limit  of $\sqrt{n}(e^{-x/n}-1)$.

Comment: Take your time to work this out. See the techniques for proving uniform convergence of a sequence.

Comment: @user92654: See the technique beneath "note" in my [answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/575042/determine-if-the-following-series-are-convergent-or-divergent/575059#575059) which helps you to find the limit.

Comment: for this question, you wanna me think in the Taylor series way?

Comment: It is a technique to find the limit. Then see if the sequence converges uniformly to this limit for $x\in[0,1]$.

Comment: I guess the sequence should unif $\to 0 for x\in [0,1]$, but i am really suffering how to prove it...

Answer (score 0):

One doesn't need the full strength of Taylor's theorem. By Mean Value Theorem, there is some $\xi \in[0,x/n]$ such that $|\frac{e^{-x/n} - 1}{x/n}| = e^{-\xi} \le 1.$ Thus
$$ \sqrt{n} \frac{e^{-x/n} - 1}{x} \le \frac{1}{\sqrt n} \to 0.$$ 
So  the integrand uniformly converges to $0$, which means that the integral is 0.