# How to check if the series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}$ is convergent

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

or divergent??

I tried few tests, but I didn't success to discover if the series  is convergent or is divergent...

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}$$

Thank you!

Comment: This problem is not well-defined.  Take $n=0$. Are we allowing complex-valued summands?

Comment: This is just a telescoping series. So what do you get as a result? Then just turn this into rigour.

Comment: Sorry there was a typing mistake. I fix it!

Comment: @ChrisK - can you help me now?

Comment: I see a divergent series based on comparison with $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac 1{\sqrt {2n}}$...

Comment: @abiessu -  How do you see it?

Comment: If we take the conjugate ($\frac 1{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt n}=\sqrt {n+1}-\sqrt n$) then the comparison is clear.

Comment: @YoavFridman, when you take the sum from $0$ to $N$, you get $\sqrt{N} - \sqrt{0} = \sqrt{N}$. Now we can always take $k$ sufficiently large such that $|\sqrt{N} - \sqrt{k}|>\varepsilon$ where we let $\varepsilon>0$. So, if you treat the series like a sequence, it is not Cauchy. So, by contrapositive, the series can't be convergent.

Comment: It's telescoping.  I don't see why anyone would approach the problem in a more complicated way.

Comment: A correction to my earlier comment... should be $\sqrt{N+1}$ and not $\sqrt{N}$ but the idea stays the same.

Comment: @YoavFridman : It's a telescoping series.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $S_n$ be the sequence of partial sums:
$$S_n = \sum_{k=0}^n \sqrt{k+1} - \sqrt{k}$$
It is easy to see that $S_0 = 1$ and by telescoping
$$S_n = \sqrt{n+1}$$
Since convergence of a series is defined through convergence of the partial sums and since $S_n$ obviously diverges, the series diverges as well.

Answer (score 2):

First, note that

> $$ a_n=\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}=\frac{1}{ \sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}\sim_{n\to \infty} \frac{1}{2\sqrt{n}}=b_n $$

Now, use the following [result](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/575042/determine-if-the-following-series-are-convergent-or-divergent/575059#575059) and see what you get.