# Why does the following series diverges?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Why does the following series diverges?
$$\sum_{i=1}^\infty \tan(\frac{\pi}{i+2})$$

Comment: A [related problem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/575042/determine-if-the-following-series-are-convergent-or-divergent/575059#575059).

Comment: It's easily solved by the comparison test to the harmonic series.

Answer (score 4):

Since by the Taylor series we have
$$\tan x\sim_0 x$$
so
$$\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{i+2}\right)\sim_{i\to\infty}\frac{\pi}{i+2}\sim_{i\to\infty}\frac{\pi}{i}$$
hence your series is divergent.

Answer (score 1):

For $x$ small, $\tan(x) > x / 2$. So your series, after the first few terms, is term by term greater than $\sum_i \frac{\pi}{2(i+2)}$. Factor out a $\frac{\pi}{2}$, and you've got something that's greater than the tail of the harmonic series.

Comment: I think "$x$ small" needs to be quantified...  perhaps you can elaborate and give an argument that covers the full infinite spectrum of $x$?

Comment: @abiessu I disagree; there is no need to quantify "small", since comparison with *any* tail of the harmonic series gives the desired result.

Comment: @AndreasBlass: well, John has left out the comparison for $\tan(x)$ when $x$ is "not small", so I think it is still important...

Comment: @abiessu As I said, I disagree; I don't think the comparison for "not small" values is relevant to this question.

Comment: @AndreasBlass: I respect your opinion, but I don't (and I expect the OP won't) understand *why* leaving out the "not small" portion is valid in this case.