# Mclaurin on $\arccos(\frac{n^2-1}{n^2+1})$

Tags: limits, education

I have expanded $\lim_{n\to \infty} \arccos(\frac{n^2-1}{n^2+1})$ to $\arccos(1-\frac{2}{n^2})$ and now i dont know what to do. I wrote the function on walfram alpha and he told me that the result is $\frac{2}{n}+\frac{1}{3n^3}+O((\frac{1}{n})^6)$ you can explain to me how that result came out from where?

Comment: walfram alpha seems like a great guy.

Comment: See this [technique](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/575042/determine-if-the-following-series-are-convergent-or-divergent).

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal you helped me indirectly, to solve another doubt! thx! :)

Comment: @malloc: you are welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, for $x\in [0,+\infty[$,

$$\arccos \frac{1-x^2}{1+x^2}=2\arctan x$$

To see why, write $x=\tan \theta$ for $\theta \in[0,\pi/2[$, then $\theta=\arctan x$ and

$$\frac{1-x^2}{1+x^2}=\frac{1-\tan^2 \theta}{1+\tan^2 \theta}=\frac{\cos^2\theta -\sin^2\theta}{\cos^2\theta +\sin^2\theta}=\cos 2\theta$$

And since $2\theta \in [0,\pi[$, $\arccos(\cos2\theta)=2\theta$

Now, for $|x|<1$

$$\arctan x=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \frac{x^{2n+1}}{2n+1}$$

And (don't forget to rename the sum variable)

$$\arccos \frac{n^2-1}{n^2+1}=\arccos \frac{1-1/n^2}{1+1/n^2}=2\sum_{k=0}^\infty  \frac{(-1)^k}{(2k+1)n^{2k+1}}$$

By the way, since the LHS in the first equation is even, and the RHS is odd, you get, for any $x \in \Bbb R$,

$$\arccos \frac{1-x^2}{1+x^2}=2|\arctan x|$$

One way to "guess" the result in the first place, is to remember the half-angle formula: if $x=\tan (\theta/2)$, then $\cos \theta = \frac{1-x^2}{1+x^2}$.

---

**Edit, for malloc**

Here is a slightly different proof.

In the above, I apply the development of $\arctan$ on $]-1,1[$, and I let $x=1/n$.

But, still using

$$\arccos \frac{1-x^2}{1+x^2}=2\arctan x$$

And with $x=n$, we can also use the development of $\arctan$ at $\infty$. For this, you will need, for $x>0$:

$$\arctan x + \arctan \frac 1 x = \frac {\pi}2$$

Thus if $n=x >1$ (so that the development of $\arctan \frac 1x$ holds),

$$\arctan n = \frac {\pi}2-\arctan \frac 1 n = \frac{\pi}{2}-\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k \frac{(\frac{1}{n})^{2k+1}}{2k+1}$$

And finally (since $\arccos (-x)=\pi-\arccos(x)$),

$$\arccos \frac{n^2-1}{n^2+1}=\pi-\arccos \frac{1-n^2}{1+n^2}$$
$$=\pi-2\arctan n=\pi-2\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k \frac{(\frac{1}{n})^{2k+1}}{2k+1}\right)$$

$$\arccos \frac{n^2-1}{n^2+1}=2\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k \frac{(\frac{1}{n})^{2k+1}}{2k+1}$$

Comment: but the expantion of $2arctg(x)$ is $\pi-\frac{2}{n}+\frac{2}{3 n^3}-\frac{2}{5 n^5}+O((\frac{1}{n})^7)$

Comment: @malloc Definitely not. $\arctan 0=0$, to begin with. Be careful with $\arcsin x + \arccos x = \pi/2$, maybe it's what hurts you here.

Comment: finally i understand.. only one thing why wolfram alpha put the $\pi$, in the expansion?

Comment: @malloc You probably asked by mistake $\arccos ((1-n^2)/(1+n^2))$ to WolframAlpha, while it's really $\arccos ((n^2-1)/(n^2+1))$. And since $\arccos (-x)=\pi-\arccos (x)$...

Comment: I asked $2arctan(x)$, I checked!

Comment: @malloc But I get $2 x-(2 x^3)/3+(2 x^5)/5+O(x^6)$ (see [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2+arctan%28x%29))

Comment: you must see the expansion for x to infinity http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=lim+x-%3E+infinity+2arctan%28x%29

Comment: To **infinity**. Of course it's not the same expansion! The one I give is at 0 (notice I wrote $|x|<1$). Now to get the expansion at infinity, just use $\arctan (x) + \arctan (1/x) = \mathrm{sign}(x) \pi/2$. Hence the $\pi$ lying in the result!

Comment: You can change your answer, so I'll see if I can better understand?

Comment: @malloc Done...

Answer (score 0):

$\lim_{n\to \infty}= arccos{\frac{n^2-1}{n^2+1}}=arccos\left({1-\frac{2}{n^2+1}}\right)$

So as $n\to\infty$ this goes to $arccos(1)$ which is equal to $0$.

Comment: I know this, but i must expand it with maclaurin

Comment: It's just the taylor expansion of this function at $x=0$. You can use the taylor expansion formulae at $x=0$. It's here :http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MaclaurinSeries.html. It is tiresome but not hard.