# How to prove the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(\frac{1}n)}n$ converges?

Tags: sequences-and-series

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(\frac{1}n)}n$$

Using the comparison test/limit comparison test? I have tried the comparison test and several attempts at the limit comparison test, but everything I try points to divergence, which I know isn't true.

Comment: You might be able to do something with [Dirichlet's Test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_test)

Comment: Compare with one half of the harmonic series, i.e., consider those n where $\cos\tfrac1n>\tfrac12$. And please give the reasons that make you exclude divergence.

Comment: Sorry, I meant sin, not cos!

Comment: Just compare with $1/n^2$.

Comment: $|\sin(x)|\le \min(1,|x|)$.

Comment: Mariano, could I not compare $1/n$ to $1/n^2$ by that logic?

Comment: Not at all. Have you tried computing the limit of the quotient of the general term of your series with $1/n^2$? (Or the inequality $0\leq \tfrac1n\sin\tfrac1n\leq\tfrac1{n^2}$.

Comment: LutzL, my reasons only include WolframAlpha

Comment: The question for reasons was from before the change from $\cos$ to $\sin$.

Comment: Just for your information (hoping that this could be of any interest) : the infinite sum is $1.47283$ while the infinite sum of $1/n^2$ is $\pi^2/6=1.64493$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The series is convergent:

$$
0\le \frac{\sin\frac 1n}{n} \le \frac{\frac 1n}{n} = \frac 1{n^2} 
$$ and $\sum \frac 1{n^2} <\infty$.

Comment: Thanks! Would you mind pointing out the error in my logic of using the limit comparison test with $b_n=\frac1n$ and using L'Hôpital's?

Comment: @rosstex, edti the question to include your reasoning. It is not possible to  point out the error in what you did if you do not tell us, well, what you did!

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez Sorry, I'm just getting used to Latex! You guys are very helpful, I'm on it

Comment: I now see the error I made, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** when $x\sim 0$, then

$$ \sin x \sim x. $$

A   [related technique](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/575042/determine-if-the-following-series-are-convergent-or-divergent).

Comment: Thanks, I would upvote you if I had more reputation!

Comment: You are welcome.