# Convergence of $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac {\ln(1+e^{-n})}{n}. $

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, divergent-series

For homework (Calculus 2) I have to determine does this series converge or diverge and I don't know how to start:

> $$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac {\ln(1+e^{-n})}{n}. $$

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Hint:** For $x\gt 0$, we have $\ln(1+x)\lt x$.

**Remark:** This inequality has many proofs. One way is to exponentiate. We get the equivalent inequality $1+x\lt e^x$, which is clear from the power series of $e^x$. Or else we can let $f(x)=x-\ln(1+x)$. Note that $f(0)=0$ and $f'(x)\gt 0$ when $x\gt 0$.

Answer (score 2):

For large $n$, we have

> $$ \ln(1+e^{-n}) \sim e^{-n}. $$

See [related techniques](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/575042/determine-if-the-following-series-are-convergent-or-divergent).

Comment: Can I say: $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac {ln(1+e^{-n})}{n} \sim \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac {e^{-n}}{n}$ and now use d'Alembert's ratio test?

Comment: @Nick: $\frac{1}{ne^{n}}\leq \frac{1}{e^n}$.

Answer (score 0):

$1+e^{-n}>e^{-n}\Rightarrow \ln (1+e^{-n})> \ln e^{-n}=-n$

So, $\dfrac {\ln(1+e^{-n})}{n}> ??$

What can you conclude?

Comment: $\dfrac {\ln(1+e^{-n})}{n}> -1$ and the origianl series is greater then the series of -1 which is divergent. Am I right?

Comment: I don't think anything interesting about convergency can be concluded, perhaps because the inequalities are trivial and yield *negative* terms on one of their sides...

Comment: @DonAntonio : I was hoping that $\dfrac {\ln(1+e^{-n})}{n}> -1$ implies $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac {\ln(1+e^{-n})}{n}> \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} -1$  left hand side is divergent so would be right hand side.. then i realized comparision test is valid only for positive terms.... I realize my mistake....

Answer (score 0):

When you have this kind of series delete the constant value and try to apply some basic property. For the firsts exercises this should be enough.

You can approximate the $\ln(1+e^{-n})$ to $ e^{-n}$ and :

$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac {\ln(1+e^{-n})}{n} \sim \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac {e^{-n}}{n}.$$
So..try to continue by yourself

Comment: This answer has an error. Simply check `[n=2,log(1+exp(-n))]   \\  = [2, 0.126928011043]`,
`[n=10,log(1+exp(-n))]  \\  = [10, 0.0000453988992169]` 
`[n=100,log(1+exp(-n))] \\  = [100, 3.72007597602 E-44]`

Comment: Removed the downvoting due to correction of the long-time ignored error in formula.