# Why does $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}$ diverge?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

Why does $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}$ diverge?

Using the ratio test I get the following. First of all since $u_n=\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}=(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n})\frac{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}$

Then $\left| \frac{u_{n+1}}{u_n} \right|=\frac{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n+2}+\sqrt{n+1}}\lt 1$.

By the ratio test, the series should converge, but it does not. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: That ratio may be less than $1$, but its limit _equals_ $1$, so the Ratio Test is inconclusive.

Comment: Because $$s_n =\sum_{k=1}^n (\sqrt{k+1}-\sqrt{k} )=\sqrt{n+1} -1\to\infty$$

Comment: for one: $ \frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1} + \sqrt{n}} > \frac{1}{\sqrt{n} + \sqrt{n}} = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{n}}$ which is known to diverge since it is a p series with power constant less than 1

Comment: Thanks guys, I forgot that the ratio needs to be less than 1 for all n greater than some $n_0$.

Comment: @frogeyedpeas I think your inequality is wrong, probably meant to have some $+1$'s

Comment: "Thanks guys...": No, you have missed the point. In this case, the ratio _is_ less than $1$ for all $n$ greater than some $n_0$ $-$ for instance, $n_0 = 1$. But the ratio _tends to_ $1$ as $n$ tends to $\infty$, so the ratio test is inconclusive.

Comment: @TonyK Well but if the ratio converges to 1, then by definition there exists an $n_0 : \forall n \geq n_0 : \left| \left| \frac{a_n+1}{a_n} \right| -1 \right | \lt \epsilon$. So how can the ratio be less than 1 for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$? Doesn't the limit imply that they are essentially the same given a large enough value for n?

Comment: Your understanding of the ratio test seems to be at fault. What is the ratio test, in your view?

Comment: Quoting from my lecture notes: "Let $(a_k)_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of real numbers with $a_k \neq 0, \forall k \geq \hat{k} \in \mathbb{N}$. If there exists a $q \in (0,1)$ and a $k_0 \geq \hat{k}: \left|\frac{a_{k+1}}{a_k} \right| \leq q, \forall k \geq k_0$ then $\sum a_k$ converges absolutely."

Comment: Yes, exactly. What is your $q$?

Comment: Ok I think you can't pick one, since for any $q \in (0,1)$ there would come an $n \in \mathbb{N}$ for which q would be smaller than that value. Is that the reason why you cannot use the ratio test here?

Comment: Yes, exactly!${}$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The ratio test actually doesn't conclude anything. Note that
$$
\frac{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n+2}+\sqrt{n+1}} = \frac{\sqrt{1 + 1/n} + 1}{\sqrt{1+2/n}+\sqrt{1+1/n}} \to \frac{1+1}{1+1} = 1
$$

Now notice that for large $n$ we have
$$
n > 2\sqrt{n+1} > \sqrt{n+1} + \sqrt{n} \implies \frac{1}{n} < \frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}
$$
So we get that the series diverges.

Answer (score 1):

First we write the summand as

$$ a_n=(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n})\frac{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}} \sim_{n\to \infty} \frac{1}{2\sqrt{n}}=b_n, $$

then we use the [comparison test](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/575042/determine-if-the-following-series-are-convergent-or-divergent):

> Suppose $\sum_{n} a_n$ and $\sum_n b_n $ are series with positive terms, then
>
> if $\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{a_n}{b_n}=c>0$, then either both series converge or diverge.