# if $a_n>0$ and $\sum a_n$ converges, so does $\sum \dfrac{a_n}{a_{n}+1}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Ive tried to prove that the partial sums of $\dfrac{a_n}{a_{n}+1}$ are bounded, but besides of writing it as the sum $1-\dfrac{1}{a_{n}+1}$, I cannot imagine how to do it...

Comment: Well as each term $0< a_n/(a_n+1) < a_n/1 = a_n$ then the sum of the terms must be $0 < \sum a_n/(a_n+1) < \sum a_n$ so ...

Comment: Oh, it was easier than I thought. So I guess we can generalize replacing $a_n +1$ by $b_n$, with the condition that $b_n>a_n$ from some $n$ onwards

Comment: You should have a theorem in your aresenal that if $a_n \rightarrow a$ and $b_n \rightarrow b$ and $b_n < c_n < a_n$ and monotonic (so it doesn't "bounce" between a and b) then $c_n $ converges.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note this

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \dfrac{a_n}{a_n(a_{n}+1) }=1$$

Which implies that the series converges since $\sum_n a_n$ does (by comparison theory test). See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/575042/determine-if-the-following-series-are-convergent-or-divergent).

Comment: I think yours is best. It doesn't even use that $a_n>0$

Comment: @Diego:In fact the comparison theorem requires both series to be $>0$ but it is easy and efficient!

Comment: I mean both series have positive terms.

Comment: Yeah,I meant that it could be $a_n<0$ too.

Comment: @Diego I am not sure you got the point the first time so let me reiterate: **the result is false if one does not assume that $a_n>0$**.

Comment: @Did As far as I see, the limit comparision theorem holds too if the sequences to compare are both negative from some $N$ onwards. Furthermore, it holds even if one is negative and the other positive from some $N$. In particular, if $-1<a_n<0$ from some $M$, then $\dfrac{a_n}{a_{n}+1}$ is negative after that $M$, too. So the result follows.

Comment: @Diego This is not the point: if $(a_n)$ is real valued, the signs can alternate--and then the result fails.

Comment: Indeed, it's not necessary to add $-1<a_n<0$ as an additional hypothesis, since it follows from the facts that $a_n$ converges to 0 and $a_n<0$

Comment: Yeah, I agree that if $a_n$ alternates the result does not follow.

Answer (score 2):

We have $a_n>0$, then $a_n+1>1$ and
$$
0<\dfrac{a_n}{a_{n}+1}<a_n
$$
giving
$$
0<\sum\dfrac{a_n}{a_{n}+1}<\sum a_n.
$$ The series is **convergent**.

Comment: You used comparison basically!