# $ \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \frac{(2^j)+ j}{(3^j) - j} $ converges

Tags: convergence-divergence

Show the series $ \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \frac{(2^j)+ j}{(3^j) - j} $ converges.

I have looked at an answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/569739/how-to-show-that-sum-2j-j-over-3j-j-converges), but I do not understand what these results give us. For example, in the first answer:

> $$\frac{2^j + j}{3^j - j} \le \frac{2^j + 2^j}{3^j - j} \le \frac{2^j + 2^j}{3^j - \frac{1}{2} 3^j}$$

What do we do with the last expression? I understand we want to compare it with something, but don't see what.

Comment: [Here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/571119/show-the-series-sum-j-1-infty-frac2j-j3j-j-converges) is the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**: $$\frac{2^j + 2^j}{3^j - \frac 12 3^j} = \frac{2^{j+2}}{3^j} = 4 (\frac{2}{3})^j$$

What kind of series is this?

Regarding the inequality:

The first is clearly true since $2^j > j$ for all $j \geq 1$. The second is true for $j < \frac{1}{2} 3^j$ (which is true for $j \geq 1$) since the sum is larger when the denominator is less. Then by comparison, since this geometric series converges, so does the original series.

Comment: Hmm, I understand why the final series converges, but could you please elaborate on the steps more?

Comment: @kiwifruit I have updated the post to answer